# Meteor Build Failed: "Android target: android: Command failed with exit code ENOENT"

Tags: android, meteor

I'm attempting to build my meteor project for android. On attempting to build for android, I get the following error:

[image: Android Target?]

I'm not sure how to fix this, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Install the android build tools for the target api version that you are using.

Comment: I have Android Studio installed and have added the SDK tools through that. I'm not sure what else I would need to do to install the build tools. I'm using ubuntu if that's helpful

Comment: a most unhelpful answer, looks more like an attempt to increase the number of answers you've supplied, than to provide a resolution.  solution: fix the problem ..  thanks!!